# how to save image frame?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find the Average of 10 images and below code doing this very well as I see using imshow() but when I try to save resultant image it save a totally black image.
Someone please tell me what is problem with my code?

```
int main(){
cv::Mat frame32f,temp;
char filename[40];
Mat mean;
const int count =10;
const int width  =474;
const int height = 266;
cv::Mat resultframe = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
for(int i = 1 ; i<= count; i++){
    sprintf(filename,"%d.JPG",i);
    cout<<filename;
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat frame(img);

    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
    resultframe +=frame32f;
    frame.release();
}
resultframe *= (1.0/count/255);
imwrite("avg.jpg",resultframe);
imshow("previous",resultframe);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

I also try this but unable.

```
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
compression_params.push_back(9);

try {
    imwrite("result.png", mat, compression_params);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean average of 10 images?

Comment: you can say Mean of images.. I used it to remove noise or little bit changes in images captured with a fixed camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imwrite/imread can't handle float data, so convertTo() uchar before saving.

```
Mat bgr24;
resultframe.convertTo(bgr24, CV_8U);
imwrite("lala.jpg",bgr24);
```

(oh, and btw, please before the division)

Comment: Its giving exception now. Can you please run my whole code with your modification and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you dividing by **255**?

Try dividing by **1.0/count**.

Also, if you know the value of **count** beforehand, do the dividing before the addition.

Comment: To normalize the pixel value in the range(0-255). If I remove 255 it shows a total white image.

Comment: I think problem is not there because imshow() showing result that requred, But unable to save that result.